# Using model data in the deleted() function of a Laravel observer

Tags: php, laravel, observers, laravel-nova

I am currently developing a script to synchronize the data stored in my database with an external API. That is to say that all the records created/deleted must also be created/deleted on the external API I use.

For that, I use the [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers) proposed by Eloquent.

When a record is created, it triggers the created() function of my Observer in which I put a Job in charge of creating the record on my external API.

```
public function created(Company $company)
{
    dispatch(new ExternalAPICreateCustomer($company));
}
```

I would like to do the same thing for deletion, the problem is that the deleted() function is triggered once the record is deleted, so I can't reuse the data of the (deleted) record to make my request to my external API.

deleted() function :

```
public function deleted(Company $company)
{
    dispatch(new ExternalAPIDeleteCustomer($company));
}
```

handle() function in my Job :

```
public function handle()
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'X-Api-Key' => 'API-KEY',
        'X-Api-Secret' => 'API-SECRET'
    ])->delete('https://EXTERNAL.API/v1/customers/' . $this->company->collection_identifier);
}
```

I get an error, because my "Company" object is already deleted during the execution of the Job that requires one of its values.

I thought of using the deleting() function instead of deleted() but it is not possible because Laravel Nova (which I use) does not support it.

Do you have any idea how to do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: can we have a look at the `ExternalAPIDeleteCustomer` class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use soft delete. And after make request you can force delete you model.